# VBA: Arrays and Global Variable Declarations

Tags: arrays, excel, global-variables, scope, vba

I need to declare an array in VBA that will be used by every function. However, I cannot declare it as a global as I would do in C++.

My code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
 Dim test(0 to 10) as String

 test(0) = "avds"
 test(1) = "fdsafs"
 ....
```

The following conceptualizes what I am trying to do.

```
 public function store() as boolean
  Worksheets("test").cells(1,1) = test(0)
 End Function
```

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For global declaration, change Dim to Public like so:

```
Public test(0 to 10) as String
```

You can call this like (assuming it is in Module1, else change Module1 to whatever you've named it):

```
Module1.test(0) = "something"
```

Or simply:

```
test(0) = "something"
```

Comment: This kind of works.  You still cannot define the values of the `test` array outside of a `Sub` or `Function`.

Answer (score 6):

Why wouldn't you create everything in a class? That's the reason why classes where invented after all.

Consider the `Class1` definition

```
Option Explicit

Private m_data() As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim m_data(0 To 10)
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Erase m_data
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Integer
    Count = UBound(m_data) - LBound(m_data) + 1
End Property

Public Property Get Data(index As Integer) As String
    Data = m_data(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Data(index As Integer, value As String)
    m_data(index) = value
End Property

Public Function Store(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Store = (rng.value = m_data(0))
End Function
```

You can add all the functions you want that can access your array just like `Store()`.
with the test code in a worksheet of

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim c As New Class1

    c.Data(0) = "January"

    Debug.Print c.Store(Cells(1, 1))
End Sub
```

You can also cache the location of the cell where it is referencing, or used an assumed named argument and only supply a reference to the worksheet once after class initialization.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Public` keyword to declare a variable that you need to access in any module.

Remember that in vba you cannot declare variables or code outside of procedures.

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843144) for more information

Answer (score 1):

I have a recommendation that is a bit lighter than a class (although class is a great recommendation)

### Option 1

Define your desired constant array as a delimited string constant:

```
Public Const cstrTest = "String 1;String 2; String 3; String 4; String 5; String 6"
```

Next, whenever you need it just use Split to create an array with minimal code:

```
Dim arrStrings
arrStrings = Split (cstrTest, ";")
```

### Option 2

You might replace (or combine with Option 1) a simple public function

```
Public Function constStringArray() As String()

    constStringArray = Split (cstrTest, ";")

End Function
```

So then, in use...

```
Dim arrStrings

'Option 1 example
arrStrings = Split (cstrTest, ";")

'Option 2 example
arrStrings = constStringArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

one can do it (with global initialization) via `Static Property` quite straight-forward without creating a class or string parsing - as described in detail and with examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646199/1915920)