# VBA Passing Class Arrays to Functions

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, collections

Apologies if I am making some amateur mistakes, but I am new to VBA.
I'm trying to populate an array declared inside of a class as a property, but something's going wrong. After much searching I have two questions that I can't seem to find anywhere else:

1 - Is there a simpler way to accomplish saving data to an array-like structure that I can pass to functions from a sub? The array-like structure needs to be resizable because I will not know how many components I will add until each iteration of a loop checks those conditions.

2 - How do I correctly accomplish the passing of the array property in my class correctly to another function? It's frustrated me enough that I would like to know how it can be done if only to understand what I was doing wrong or, perhaps, what misunderstanding I had of the way VBA works. 

**Code structure follows:** 

I have declared a `Segments` property inside of a `CTask` class like this:

```
Private pSegments() As CSegment

Public Property Get Segments() As CSegment()
    Segments = pSegments()
End Property
Public Property Get segment(index As Integer) As CSegment
    segment = pSegments(index)
End Property
Public Property Let Segments(Value() As CSegment)
    pSegments() = Value()
End Property
```

I pass the `CTask` from a `Sub`, where it is defined to `populateTasks` using this code:

```
Dim tasks() As CTask
ReDim tasks(1 To 10)
Call populateTasks(tasks)
```

When I do this, the `populateTasks` code receives it using the following code:

```
Function populateTasks(ByRef tasks() As CTask)
```

I then try to call another function from `populateTasks` called `populateSegments` like this:

```
Call populateSegments(tasks(icount).Segments)
```

I receive segments array inside `populateSegments` like this:

```
Function populateSegments(ByRef Segments() As CSegment)
```

The last two code snippets are where the problem resides. The segments array is populating correctly **inside** the `populateSegments` function, but when I check the array to see if it is empty just below the call to `populateSegments` there isn't anything in the `tasks(icount).segments` array. Thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Your property returns a copy of the array. You need to populate the copy and then assign that back to the property in order to update the array in the class.

Comment: @Rory So I need to use AndyBrazil's solution or something similar?

Comment: You don't have to (you can do what I described) but it makes sense to have it as a method of the cTask class.

Comment: @Rory So how would assign it back to the property in the correct way? I tried and kept getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you make populatesegments a method of cTask? That avoids the problem and is a better design

Comment: Could you give me a small example of the code to correctly pass the array to that method and the method signature so that I can be sure to do it correctly? I've tried numerous times, but keep getting errors.

Comment: This was indeed helpful in my answer, but I would also like to point to another that also helped me zero in on the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613564/vba-returning-array-from-property-get). After I made the populateSegments a method of cTask, I wasn't getting an item from pSegments, given the index, for some reason. I created a custom method, rather than a property, to simply return one item from pSegments, given an index, and it works just fine now. Thanks for your help, everyone.