# Create a class indexed property which accepts values via assignment

Tags: vba

I am writing a VBA class and trying to create a property which allows to set the value of an array item through assignment (`=` operator).

Something similar to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259714(v=vs.60).aspx

So the signature will be like : `object.PropertyName(index) = string`

Is it possible in VBA?  If yes, then can you please explain how.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer here [VBA - Returning array from Property Get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864377/3848861)

> ```
> Private v() As Double
> Public Property Get Vec(index As Long) As Double
>     Vec = v(index)
> End Property
> Public Property Let Vec(index As Long, MyValue As Double)
>     v(index) = MyValue
> End Property
> ```